# Jenkins pipeline script from SCM doesn't show configuration

Tags: jenkins, version-control, jenkins-pipeline

I'm running Jenkins on docker (ver.2.176.1) lately I found out that Jenkins pipeline script from SCM doesn't show his configuration in the UI as you can see in the below picture:
[image: Jenkins pipeline script from SCM doesn't show configuration]

needless to say that I have the right configuration their that's point to the Jenkins file and repository and saved but every time I come back to "configuration" it all disappear.
**I don't remember updating any plugin related to pipeline.**

in the job XML I do see all my configuration:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We hat the same issue. Downgrading of the plugin "Prometheus metrics" from 2.0.6 to 2.0.0 fixed it:  https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-59145

Comment: I'm shocked that it worked, Do you know the reason for that?

Answer (score 0):

In our case **Mixing Security Realm** plugin caused the same issue. As we actually didn't use it we just removed this plugin and it worked.